# i have two images in a div tag and would like to add hyperlinks to these images upon clicking them. any ideas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, hyperlink, webforms

I have two images in a div tag and would like to add hyperlinks to these images upon clicking them. any ideas?

Comment: this is what i have so far<div class="images">
                            
         <img class="facebook" src="../fb.jpg"  /> 

           <img class="twitter" src="../twitter.jpg"  />
                   
               
               </div>

Answer (score 3):

You can either give the image this attribute:

```
onclick = "window.location.href = '#yourllink'";
```

or you can nest the image in the hyperlink tag:

```
<a href="#yourlink"><img src="yourimg"/></a>
```

You can also add this to your js file:

```
function hyperlink(a){window.location.href = a;}
document.getElementById('imgid').onclick = hyperlink('your link');
```

I personally dont recommend the last one, too complicated...

Comment: tried these and they didnt work, in the end i switched it to a imagebutton, much easier <asp:ImageButton ID="facebook0" runat="server" Height="43px" ImageUrl="~/fb.jpg"
                        OnClick="facebook_Click" Width="45px" PostBackUrl="https://www.facebook.com/" />

Comment: What how come? This worked for me, how did it not work for you